# What happens in the execution context when this script is executed

Tags: javascript

When i execute the following script the alert statement is printing the function why is it so?
What happens in the execution context? Why the variable basicPattern's undefined value is not printing?

```
 function basicPattern(){
    var o = 5;

    return o;
 }

 var basicPattern;
 console.log(basicPattern);
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following - do you expect `var basicPattern;` to set it to `undefined`?

Comment: Your edited code prints `5` for me.

Comment: Did you encounter a real problem with it?

Comment: The original question made much more sense, doesn't make any sense at all now :D

Comment: @Esailija: yes, just edited back to where it was

Comment: @frenchie. Which makes me thing this is not a real question!

Comment: @gdoron: it's not a question but it's a very common beginner problem; we've all been there no?

Comment: @frenchie - That's not how it was, is it? I thought the question was about why it logged the function and not `undefined` since there was a `var basicPattern;` after the function declaration.

Comment: @JamesAllardice no there was `var basicPattern = 5;` (edited by the OP himself) `var basicPattern` would be a basic problem about understanding hoisting and `var basicPattern = 5` is just not a real question because it's simply impossible

Comment: @Esailija - I'm very confused. It started with `var basicPattern;`, which the OP edited to `var basicPattern = 5;` and now the `var` statement has completely gone!

Comment: @frenchie: I've rolled back your edit. The OP's edit should be the one we defer to.

Comment: @JamesAllardice. Every time I see people "fighting" what the OP asks, I vote for closing!

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Yes that was my point. I wanted to revert the edit but it started saying locked.

Comment: The original had `var basicPattern;` right before the `console.log`. The question was why was `basicPattern` still referring to the function definition, and not the `undefined` variable `var basicPattern`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function basicPattern(){
    var o = 5;

    return o;
 }

 var basicPattern;
 console.log(basicPattern);
```

Evaluates same as this (IE bugs disregarded):

```
 var basicPattern;

 basicPattern = function basicPattern(){
    var o = 5;

    return o;
 };

 console.log(basicPattern);
```

Since `basicPattern` was already declared, declaring it again won't have any effect since declarations
are hoisted and merged. If you had assignment to `5` it would go like this:

```
 var basicPattern;

 basicPattern = function basicPattern(){
    var o = 5;

    return o;
 };

 basicPattern = 5;

 console.log(basicPattern);
```

Read more about hoisting: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting